# Does a wireless access point behave like a hub?

Tags: router, wifi, hub

I read on Ask Leo that a wireless access point is essentially a hub.  Does that mean in my home network my wireless router (which according to the article is really a router AND wireless access point) will distribute the response to my request to everyone on the network?  Will the same thing happen in a coffee shop?

Here's another Ask Leo explaining deifference between hub, router, and switch: https://askleo.com/whats_the_difference_between_a_hub_a_switch_and_a_router/

Comment: [SF] is for professional system administration questions. End-user questions are better suited for [SU]. Network engineering questions can be asked on [networkengineering.se]. I can't make any promises about how your question would be received on either of those sites.

Comment: @kasperd well request to move to superuser was already denied by moderator.  Thanks, I swear I combed through the sites list and didn't find anything with 'network' it it.... I don't understand why the mod can't just tell me where to go instead of making me play guess-the-right-site sigh....

Comment: In order for a question to be migrated it is not enough that the question is on-topic on the target site. The question also has to be of good enough quality. I don't know what reason was given for the rejection.